# Air Conditioning units

Tags: hvac

I have 2 AC units outside of my house (1 controls the temp on the first floor while the other on the 2nd.)  The beginning of the summer season one of the units was not properly cooling its floor.
Contacted repairman he came out and added freon to both units.  Units seemed to work fine for about 1 month (at least rooms were cooled).  Went on holiday came back to both units not cooling the entire house.  Turned off both systems from the inside controls only both systems are still running outside (the fans are rotating on both units outside) and I see ice on the hoses outside.  I am not an expert but I dont think the hoses should have ice when its hot outside.  Now I am just sitting and waiting for said repairman to come check the units out.  Since both units are running nonstop outside is it safe to turn the outside power off on each unit?

Comment: If you turn the outside power off, wait 10-20 minutes before turning it back on.  Otherwise a thing called "short cycling" can happen which can damage the compressor.  The A/C normally has protection against that with an internal timer, but if you cut power the timer resets.  Also, it sounds like the freon leak was not fixed. It sometimes takes several passes to narrow down the problem, so don't fire your A/C guy for not fixing it the first time, they're A/C guys, not gods.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply @Harper-ReinstateMonica.  Would you know why there is ice on the hoses and what should I do about the ice?

Comment: it sounds like the freon leak was not fixed. It sometimes takes several passes to narrow down the problem, so don't fire your A/C guy for not fixing it the first time, they're A/C guys, not gods.

Comment: It would be very unusual for the outdoor units to continue to run if you "turned them off using inside controls".  From some of your terms (returning from holiday), I'm guessing you are not in the USA, so stuff may be wired differently there.       Regarding the frost on the pipes (tubing), if the indoor air handler wasn't operating, excessively cold temps could develop and the humidity in the air would freeze on them.   Please provide more info on where you are on this blue orb and as many details about your system as you can muster.

Comment: Icing on the outside components isn't uncommon, however, it's not part of the proper/expected operation of the AC unit. It can happen if you turned the temp up or turned the units off while you were on holiday, then turned them on to a very cold temperature when you returned. They could be running intentionally as the units to defrost themselves. Shutting power off at the breaker would turn them off, and they would defrost eventually, but the running (there may actually be a heater running) will speed the defrost, allowing them to go back to cooling more quickly.

Comment: Note that other factors can lead to icing in an AC unit as well.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson I agree that "holiday" tends to indicate "not-US-based". However the use of "AC" instead of "Air Con" does indicate US-based. This confusion can only be clarified by the OP.

Comment: @FreeMan  I get some icing on the tubing to the air handler (right where it enters the evap coils, the rest is well insulated) at my house, it's not uncommon.   But we don't know enough about the OPs system?  Mini-splits are very common in parts of the world, if a mini, maybe the OP left one of the head units turned on, so the outdoor unit keeps running.  But if it's a traditional air handler and outdoor A/C unit, it clearly shouldn't run when there is no call for AC...that of course assumes the OP used the T-stat to turn things off.

Comment: Hi All, Thank you so much for your responses.  To clarify, I am in Chicago.  The thing is the temperature wasn't changed at all, it is always set at 72. Eventually turned off both units from the outside and the fans stopped, checked the units now and the ice also melted.  I am not sure if I should turn the units back on?  I am still waiting for the repairman to call.  And to top it off our electric bill came and was almost $500, which is excessively high.  Not sure if this matters but they are both Lennox and older models.